# moving a better bottle carboy

Tags: better-bottle, fermenter

So, just out of curiosity... if I wanted / needed to relocate my primary fermentation carboy to another area of the house, what would be the safest way to do this, without risk of infection?

I know that picking the better bottle carboys up can cause the water in the fermentation lock to get sucked into the carboy, so would it make sense to just remove the airlock temporarily, cap the carboy with foil or something, move it, and then replace the fermentation lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tip it slightly so you can get your hands under it.  Get an arm underneath it as you pick it up.  That will keep the bottom from flexing downward creating that "suck" in the airlock.

If you are not comfortable with that, then you can indeed sanitize some foil and use that.  Or I'd recommend just popping off the airlock and refilling it with a small amount of sanitizer, so if any does get sucked in it won't be a big deal.  I'd only do that with a no rinse sanitizer.

However, I have had several of these suck water back in on my in the past and it hasn't been a big problem as far as contamination goes.  It just doesn't feel good when it happens.

I would strongly urge that if you are going to move it, that you should put it in a milk crate or something as you move it.  Because you are going to have to move it again when you go to rack it for bottling or what have you.

Comment: Very good and complete answer. I would just like to add that I personally use vodka instead of water in the airlock so that in case of sucking-in there is neither a chance of infection nor of change in taste.

Answer (score 2):

I bought the better bottle dry-lock. It doesn't allow any air in so when you pick it up the flexing is minimal.

It doesn't help you at the moment (brewchez's answer is what I'd recommend for the time being), but I've appreciated having the dry-lock for this very reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a stopper plug.  It is a tiny stopper for the hole in the stopper.  Dunk it in sanitizer or vodka, plug the airlock hole while you move the better bottle, and put the airlock when you are done moving it.

Comment: I sort of like that idea, but a better idea would be to just swap the whole thing for a solid bung.  Might be a little tough pulling the airlock out of the `main bung.